# Proof with ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Question:**
Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $I=(2, X) \subset R$. Prove that $X^{2}+4 \in I \cdot I$, but that $X^{2}+4$ cannot be written as $x y$, with $x, y \in I$.

I feel like this question should be very easy.

I am not sure what $I=(2,X)$ means, my textbook is not very clear on this. Product of two ideals $IJ$ is defined as $\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}y_{i} : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}, x_{i} \in I, y_{i} \in J\}$.
So is it correct if I say $I\cdot I = \{4, 2X, X^{2}\}$. And $I\cdot I$ is again an ideal so $X^{2} + 4 \in I \cdot I$, since its closed under addition.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. See [here for the reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: $I$ is the ideal generated by two elements, $2$ and $X$. So using that formula, $X^2+4$ would be in $II$ because it is $X\times X + 2\times 2$. To show why it cannot be written as $xy$, $I$ is an ideal where every element is a polynomial with even constant term (try and see why) and see if you can take it from here

Comment: Would $X^{2} + 6$ or $X^{2} + 2k$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ also be in $I \cdot I$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the roots of $X^2+4$ are $\pm 2i$, which clearly are not elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, and so $X^2+4 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is irreducible. That is, we can't write it as a product of elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that aren't units (which is just the element $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$).

The ideal $I=(x,2)=\{f\cdot x+g\cdot 2:f,g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\}$, and so $X^2+4=X \cdot X+2 \cdot 2,$ but $X^2+4$ is irreducible (as described above), and so it can't be factored into two elements of $I$.